# Unable to access one custom domain in Azure Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, azure, multisite

I have moved my WordPress multisite installation successfully to Azure. My main blog and another that I have moved work fine:
[cedarrivermusic.com](http://cedarrivermusic.com) and
[timpurdum.com](http://timpurdum.com).

However, my third site, [cedarrivertech.com](http://cedarrivertech.com), does not resolve.
`ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` or `Can't Reach` errors when using this address.
I can access the dashboard, because this resolves to `tech.cedarrivermusic.com`, but not the actual site.

I have checked all DNS records, and they are identical for all three.
The web app on Azure verifies all three addresses, as well as `*.cedarrivermusic.com`.

Not sure whether this is a WP issue or an Azure issue.

**EDIT**
I "solved" this by going into the WHM panel on the *old* server, and seeing that I had deleted the DNS zone for `cedarrivertech.com`. So I recreated the entry on the old server. Which makes absolutely no sense to me, as every ping/dns service I can find shows the new server. I'd still love suggestions on how this is happening from the old DNS zone server.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the edit, deleting a DNS zone in your old (yet active) WHM panel will cause this failure. However, I have also discovered that I can turn off the old server completely, and the new server functions correctly.

**EDIT**

Actually, turning off the WHM server does eventually cause failure again, so I am in contact with my old host/domain registrar to try to fix this.